# ListPicker control crashes app inventor 2 (ai2) when selected

Tags: app-inventor

I am having a problem programming the Pizza Party example http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/pizzaparty.html in ai2.  The biggest problem is that I can't even connect to Pizza Party using the 6 letter code.

I am able to get around this by successfully connecting one of my other projects using the 6 letter code and then switching projects to Pizza Party.  The app shows up on my android screen, but when I press either ListPicker, the list displays momentarily and then the screen goes black, subsequently prompting me for the 6 letter code again.

I am able to successfully press the submit button of the app so that's why I suspect the ListPicker.  I disabled all the blocks to make sure the code behind wasn't crashing silently.

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening and how to overcome it?

PS:  I have never been able to get the QR code scan to work

Comment: download the [source code of the Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/sites/all/files/ai2tutorials/pizzaParty/PizzaParty_MIT_2016.aia) and try again... btw. for these type of questions is would be better to ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest)... it seems to be, you also have a connection issue... make sure to use Google Chrome or Firefox... which device/Android version are you using for your tests?

Answer (score 0):

OMG I found the answer posted elsewhere!  It was a Developer Option on the phone that caused the issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/5xq5NlPXFA4/RBg6_gHcCgAJ

Thanks Peter Bowers!